# MKdocs-readTheDocs: How to set the Home page?

Tags: read-the-docs, mkdocs

Yes, this is a rookie question, but its not clear to me from the documentation how to set up the home page. I get a 404 on the home page. Not sure what its missing. Any help is really appreciated. Using git pages to publish (user name removed), the URL https://user-name.github.io/aiopslabs/ returns a 404, if I click on the sections and navigation works fine, just the home page is missing.

This is my mkdocs.yml

```
site_name: mySite
site_url: https://<user-name>.github.io/aiopslabs/
nav:
    - Start Here: integration.md
    - Log Anomaly Training: log-anomaly.md
    - Log Anomaly Inference: inference.md
    - About: about.md
theme: readthedocs
```

Comment: Do you have index.md file ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Zoran, my index.md file was missing. Adding this file created the home page.